# Post запрос в Android

Tags: android, post, retrofit

Здравствуйте. Написал код, который по моему мнению должен отправлять запрос к апи серверу, но он не работает (приложение не вылетает)

P.S не судите строго, не имел дело с post запросами, а тем более с ретрофитом

Код запроса

```
 public void registrationUserMethod (){
            final String BASE_URL = "http://u1938.blue.elastictech.org";

            Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
            stringMap.put("name", stringNameActivityRegistration);
            stringMap.put("email", stringEmailActivityRegistration);
            stringMap.put("password", stringPasswordActivityRegistration);
            stringMap.put("contact_number", stringContactNumberActivityRegistration);

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            RegistrationUserAPI registrationUserAPI = retrofit.create(RegistrationUserAPI.class);
            Call<RegistrationUserBody> call = new Call<RegistrationUserBody>() {
                @Override
                public Response<RegistrationUserBody> execute() throws IOException {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void enqueue(Callback<RegistrationUserBody> callback) {

                }

                @Override
                public boolean isExecuted() {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegistration.this, "isExecuted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void cancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegistration.this, "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public boolean isCanceled() {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegistration.this, "isCanceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public Call<RegistrationUserBody> clone() {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegistration.this, "clone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public Request request() {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegistration.this, "reguest", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return null;
                }
            };
            call.enqueue(new Callback<RegistrationUserBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<RegistrationUserBody> call, Response<RegistrationUserBody> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityRegistration.this, "Запрос выполнен успешно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityRegistration.this, "Ошибка на сервере", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<RegistrationUserBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegistration.this, "Ошибка во время выполнения запроса", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Интерфейс

```
public  interface RegistrationUserAPI {
@POST("/api/users")
 Call<RegistrationUserBody> registrationUser(@Body RegistrationUserBody registrationUserBody);}
```

Класс

```
public class RegistrationUserBody {
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
String name;

@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
String password;

@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
String email;

@SerializedName("contact_number")
@Expose
String contactNumber;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getContactNumber() {
    return contactNumber;
}
public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
}
```

Comment: ответ от api будет в формате `RegistrationUserBody ` ?

Comment: @РасулA-ев при Post запросе разве следует ожидать ответа? (я не имею ввиду ответа от сервера)

Comment: а что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Как я думаю, post запрос всего лишь вносит данные на сервер. А об ответе я не слышал

Comment: зависит от того как это реализовано

Answer (score 1):

```
Call<RegistrationUserBody> call = new Call<RegistrationUserBody>()
```

Это новый экземпляр `Call<RegistrationUserBody>`. Вместо этого надо написать

использовать `Call<RegistrationUserBody>` из вашего интерфейса. Примерно вот так

```
registrationUserAPI.registrationUser.enqueue(new Callback<RegistrationUserBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RegistrationUserBody> call, Response<RegistrationUserBody> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegistration.this, "Запрос выполнен успешно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegistration.this, "Ошибка на сервере", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RegistrationUserBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityRegistration.this, "Ошибка во время выполнения запроса", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```